# Description texts in text input field

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I would like to have description/addinional text inside text field. That text shouldnt disappear when user puts data into the field. It should just move along with it (like go more right and numbers/text that user has put in goes on left side).

Example:
Normal state:

```
 _________
|_m2______|
```

User puts some data in:

```
 ________
|_22_m2__|
```

The lines there just represents border of input field :) And that m2 is the text that should stay there always.

Hopefully you understood what i'm after. Trying to google it too, but not sure what are right words to descripe thing like that:)

Thanks.

Comment: What if user deletes m2?

Comment: Yes, that the thing. It should be done somehow so user cant delete it. Basecamp login has some sort of background text. Or is it just image?

Comment: most probably it's a background image

Answer (score 3):

Is it for something like dimensions? Well, the simplest solution - put it on the right of the field.

A better solution: make a text input auto-grow as you type, borderless, and wrap inside of a div simulating the border - makes sense?

see http://jsfiddle.net/guard/jY7vx/3/ for almost working example

the problem I see there - the text "jumps" a bit when you type. could probably be done with better margin

Comment: Your better solution actually sounds doable. Will test it atleast. Thx!

Comment: look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/guard/jY7vx/ (still playing with it, but it works)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/zF4nW/

Comment: click at the end of your box, then try pressing the left arrow key